# Canonical divisor of a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$ and $K_S$ be its canonical divisor (class). I know that $K_S^2$ refers to the self-intersection of the curve $K_S$ with itself.

What does it mean when $K_S^2=0$? This happens, for example, when $S$ is minimal and has Kodaira dimension $0$.

Also, by notation from Beauville's book page 93, what does it mean when $K_S=0$? Do we have $K_S^2 = 0 \implies K_S=0$?

Comment: The first maybe not true: consider S be K3 surface blow up a point. $K_S=E$ be the exceptional divisor. Thus $K_S^2=-1$

Comment: @PeterWu Of course I left out the important minimal assumption, I've edited accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K_S^2=0$ tells you that $K_S$ and $-K_S$ are not big, i.e. $\kappa(S)\neq -\infty, 2$.

For your second question:  if $K_S$ is trivial then $K^2_S=0$, but the other implication is false. Take a minimal Enriques surface $S$, then $K_S\neq \mathcal 0_S$, but it is torsion, namely $2K_S=\mathcal 0_S$. Therefore $4K_S^2=0$, i.e. $K_S^2=0$.
On the other hand, for a minimal surface $S$ with $\kappa(S)=1$, $K_S$ is not torsion, but $K_S^2=0$.

Comment: So there is nothing much we can do when $K^2_S = 0$ except to deduce that $\kappa(S) = 0,1$? Is $K_S$ being torsion the same as saying there exists an integer $n \geq 1$ such that $h^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(nK)) = h^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S) = 1$?

Comment: Torsion means that there exists an integer $n\geq 1$ such that $nK_S=\mathcal O_S$. The condition on the cohomology is  a consequence, but not enough, as it simply means that some plurigenus is $1$. But you may have e.g. $p_g(S)=1$ and $K_S$ not torsion (for example if $S$ is of general type).

Comment: You can deduce also other things if $K^2_S=0$. But it is a quite vagous question, as the answers depend on what you are interested in. If you want to locate your surface in the Enriques-Kodaira classification it tells you already a lot.